# Flutter Firebase email link auth - dynamic link is not working for me

Tags: android, flutter, firebase-authentication

I've followed the steps in [this guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/email-link-auth).

My dynamic link is `https://XXXXX.page.link/amTC` and it's deep link is `https://link.YYYYY.com`.

I'm able to successfully send an email link with this,

```
var acs = ActionCodeSettings(
  url: 'https://XXXXX.page.link/amTC',
  handleCodeInApp: true,
  iOSBundleId: Constants.iosBundleId,
  androidPackageName: Constants.androidPackageName,
  androidInstallApp: false,
  androidMinimumVersion: '12');

FirebaseAuth.instance.sendSignInLinkToEmail(email: 'mytest98723151@gmail.com', actionCodeSettings: acs);
```

The resulting email contains a link that appears to be well formed (it looks like `https://XXXXX.page.link/?link=https//myfirebasehost/__auth/action?apiKey=xxx&lots_of_fancy_query_params`) . However my confusion is around how to handle that link in my Android app (haven't tried iOS yet).

If I add the following intent-filter

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <data android:host="link.YYYYY.com" android:scheme="https"/>
</intent-filter>
```

then clicking the email link brings my app back into the foreground and this gets triggered

```
  FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.onLink.listen((dynamicLinkData) async {
    final Uri deepLink = dynamicLinkData.link;
    bool foo = FirebaseAuth.instance.isSignInWithEmailLink(deepLink.toString());
    logger.d('deepLink is email link? $foo');
    logger.d(dynamicLinkData.asMap());
   }
```

But the output below shows that the link isn't really working, presumably because `dynamicLinkData` is simply my deep-link url with no other data attached, when what's needed is the full dynamic link.

```
deepLink is email link? false

{
  "ios": null,
  "android": {
    "clickTimestamp": 1665438309155,
    "minimumVersion": 0
  },
  "link": "https://link.YYYYY.com",
  "utmParameters": {}
}
```

[Note that if I simply paste the entire link from the e-mail into my app and pass it to `FirebaseAuth.instance.isSignInWithEmailLink('link-from-email')` it returns 'TRUE'.]

The way I expected this should work is that I'd use an intent filter like the one below, containing the dynamic link host, not the deep link. And then by clicking the email link `FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.onLink.listen` would receive the entire dynamic link I clicked. But that doesn't happen. With the below intent filter my app is never invoked when I click the dynamic link in the email.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <data android:host="XXXXX.page.link" android:scheme="https"/>
</intent-filter>
```

I don't understand how to set up my app to properly receive the dynamic link when it's clicked from the e-mail. If anyone can explain what I'm doing wrong I'd be grateful. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Got the answer from [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/72820592#) thanks to @hansaplast. i.e In the ActionCodeSettings constructor call, using

```
androidMinimumVersion: '1'
```

and setting the intent-filter to the firebase host as below solved it.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <data android:host="ZZZZ-123456.firebaseapp.com" android:scheme="https"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Awesome!!! It worked for me after several days trying!!!